# nant <version> task

Tags: c#, .net, nant

How can I use nant  tasks to increment build versions? To be more specific how can I link this up with version numbers in assemblyinfo.cs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to consider some sort of system for managing your version increments.  One common way to do it is through continuous integration such as [CruiseControl.NET](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET).  If you go this route, you can use a build target like this:

```
<target name="set.version" description="generates the version number">
    <echo message="Setting the build version to ${CCNetLabel}..." />
    <attrib file="AssemblyInfo.cs" readonly="false" />
    <asminfo output="AssemblyInfo.cs" language="CSharp">
        <imports>
            <import namespace="System" />
            <import namespace="System.Reflection" />
        </imports>
        <attributes>
            <attribute type="AssemblyVersionAttribute" value="${CCNetLabel}" />
            <attribute type="AssemblyFileVersionAttribute" value="${CCNetLabel}" />
        </attributes>
    </asminfo>
    <attrib file="AssemblyInfo.cs" readonly="true" />
</target>
```

Where CCNetLabel is a dynamic property that is set from CruiseControl when it executes nant.

Comment: This is awesome! But I dont quite understand when to implement this in my script? Should I be performing this before the BUILD/COMPILE actually occurs? This example simply produces an "AssemblyInfo.cs" file. How can I get it to use existing AssemblyInfo.cs files in my solution? I have many.

Comment: It should be done before the compile target occurs.  The best way to use this in a solution with many existing AssemblyInfo.cs files is to isolate the version attributes and other common information for your solution (i.e. AssemblyVersion, Company, etc) into a "GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs" file that is included in all the projects for your solution.  You can modify the asminfo task above to modify that file instead.

Answer (score 3):

NAnt's [`<asminfo>` task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/asminfo.html) helps you with generating AssemblyInfo.cs.

Answer (score 3):

We use TeamCity to supply NAnt with a version number. The version number is then injected into the AssemblyInfo like this.:

```
<asminfo output="${solutionDir}/CommonAssemblyInfo.cs" language="CSharp">
      <imports>
        <import namespace="System" />
        <import namespace="System.Reflection" />
      </imports>
      <attributes>
        <attribute type="AssemblyVersionAttribute" value="${version}" />
      </attributes>
    </asminfo>
```

This creates a CommonAssemblyInfo.cs file with the specified version, which needs to be linked to all the projects in your solution.

Answer (score 2):

I am using multiple referenced projects ( Windows Forms , Class Library and BatchConsole)

Best example will be to copy the "section of Assemblyinfo" from nAnt Build file( you can download it from [Github](https://github.com/nant/nant/blob/master/NAnt.build) )

The Trick is you can use a commonAssemblyinfo file which your nAnt Targets will refer to it.

Below the target from nAnt file

```
<target name="create-common-assemblyinfo" if="${create.assemblyinfo}">
    <!-- ensure src/CommonAssemblyInfo.cs is writable if it already exists -->
    <attrib file="src/CommonAssemblyInfo.cs" readonly="false" if="${file::exists('src/CommonAssemblyInfo.cs')}" />
    <!-- generate the source file holding the common assembly-level attributes -->
    <asminfo output="src/CommonAssemblyInfo.cs" language="CSharp">
        <imports>
            <import namespace="System" />
            <import namespace="System.Reflection" />
            <import namespace="System.Runtime.InteropServices" />
        </imports>
        <attributes>
            <attribute type="ComVisibleAttribute" value="false" />
            <attribute type="CLSCompliantAttribute" value="true" />
            <attribute type="AssemblyTitleAttribute" value="NAnt" />
            <attribute type="AssemblyDescriptionAttribute" value="A .NET Build Tool" />
            <attribute type="AssemblyConfigurationAttribute" value="${project.release.type}" />
            <attribute type="AssemblyCompanyAttribute" value="http://nant.sourceforge.net" />
            <attribute type="AssemblyProductAttribute" value="NAnt" />
            <attribute type="AssemblyCopyrightAttribute" value="Copyright (C) 2001-${datetime::get-year(datetime::now())} Gerry Shaw" />
            <attribute type="AssemblyTrademarkAttribute" value="" />
            <attribute type="AssemblyCultureAttribute" value="" />
            <attribute type="AssemblyVersionAttribute" value="${project.version}.${build.number}.0" />
            <attribute type="AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute" value="${project.version}" />
        </attributes>
    </asminfo>
</target>
```